# Should I use try-catch when calling jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

So, I have jquery plugins (or any other plugins / functions / libraries, for what matters).

I was wondering if I should call the plugin inside a try-catch in order to avoid aty undefined type errors, which may possibly block the execution of the rest of the script.

This is how/where I call the plugins right now.

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // jquery plugin
        try {
            $("#app").plugin();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

        // some other function applied to entire document
        try {
            libraryFunction();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I know this is not code review, but if you have any suggestions on how to improve this code, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dealt with scenarios when a plugin error actually screwed the rest of the script and using try-catch to call the plugin solved the problem.

Using try-catch a lot may slow down your script, but unless you're dealing with long loops, the performance change will be unnoticeable.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good practice to handle unknown behavior with a try-catch block. But even more important is to know how to handle the exception once its caught. In the above code, the exception is only being logged(which is good) and nothing else. In that case your execution may still get blocked.

Additionally, it would be good to also throw the exception back to the caller and make it handle the behavior. For example, in the above code, if jquery threw an exception, you may let the caller know about the exception and the caller may decide to call the function again or do something else.

In short, after catching, handling decides how your execution will recover. Logging alone will not help.

Edit:

An example to show why an exception should be thrown back:

Lets say I have an AppThread that requests a worker thread to store some data in an SQL database. Such a code flow will ideally not require the worker thread to return anything to the caller because the Worker Thread simply executes some Insert statements. 
Now, during the insertion, worker thread caught an SQLException and simply logged and returned. Now the app Thread was never notified of this exception and it simply assumes that the data was inserted as requested. After sometime, the AppThread now wants to read the same data from the Database and asks the WorkerThread to fetch it using some Id. This time, the code will not throw any exception and the result set will simply be null. Now remember, the AppThread was sure that the data would be present and will not know what to do if the result set is null. So in one way, the code execution gets blocked after sometime of the exception.

Now, had the Worker Thread notified the exception to the App Thread earlier, the AppThread would have been aware and would have reattempted the insert operation or would show a dialog to the user letting her/him know that the data may need to be verified before attempting insert again. Also as the exception was passed back, its message would give more hints of what went wrong to the user directly. He will not have to go back to the logs to check what went wrong.

Comment: Can you give a scenario when execution is still blocked even with try-cacth?